# How to compare money field value with a calculated value (i.e. Quantity * UnitPrice) in SQL

Tags: sql

*AmountApplied* is a money field. When doing a select on this field the results look like this:
250.00

*Quantity* is an int field and *UnitPrice* is a money field.
When I do:

```
Select (Quantity * UnitPrice) as Total
```

it returns a result like this:
250.0000

When I do this it doesn't consider them the same:

```
CASE WHEN AmountApplied = Total THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as PaidInFull
```

Probably because it is comparing 250.00 and 250.0000

Can someone tell me what I should be doing differently to compare these values?

Answer (score 0):

Ahh I figured it out. Total was NULL because you can't use a custom alias later on in a select.

This did the trick:

```
CASE WHEN AmountApplied = (Quantity * UnitPrice) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as PaidInFull
```

I wouldn't have posted this  in here, but I thought it had something to do with decimals.